# How can i make an iteration with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to xml
I need to transform a xml to a output that i need and I'm having some issues regarding an iteration, I have tried some solutions, but I can't find the answer to this.

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/INT0254_JDDATIO_039_Workday_to_Datio_Worker-Work_Experience_Outbound_RD">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:ID_de_empleado>00003500294</wd:ID_de_empleado>
        <wd:Experiencia_profesional wd:Descriptor="Área de Banca Digital.">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">868c37d3d78a018259d077c51324125a</wd:ID>
        </wd:Experiencia_profesional>
        <wd:Experiencia_profesional wd:Descriptor="Data Mining.">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">868c37d3d78a016db4ca77c51324115a</wd:ID>
        </wd:Experiencia_profesional>
        <wd:Experiencia_profesional_actual wd:Descriptor="Área de Banca Digital.">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">8aa7dafe374c01f1e46edbd5fc005406</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Work_Experience_ID">WORK_EXPERIENCE#046</wd:ID>
        </wd:Experiencia_profesional_actual>
        <wd:Experiencia_profesional_actual wd:Descriptor="Data Mining.">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">8aa7dafe374c01898cb537d6fc004b07</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Work_Experience_ID">WORK_EXPERIENCE#125</wd:ID>
        </wd:Experiencia_profesional_actual>
        <wd:Experiencia_profesional_group>
            <wd:Skill_Reference_ID>046</wd:Skill_Reference_ID>
        </wd:Experiencia_profesional_group>
        <wd:Experiencia_profesional_group>
            <wd:Skill_Reference_ID>125</wd:Skill_Reference_ID>
        </wd:Experiencia_profesional_group>
        <wd:Posición wd:Descriptor="00462564 Risk Planning Associate Business Execution">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">5106f74a8f920160182b2d6a5501e872</wd:ID>
        </wd:Posición>
        <wd:Posición_group>
            <wd:ID_de_referencia wd:Descriptor="BCO.BILBAO VIZCAYA ARGENTARIA">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f5e10d5b686401c92bb4c87d34130349</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">001</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Company_Reference_ID">001</wd:ID>
            </wd:ID_de_referencia>
        </wd:Posición_group>
        <wd:Empresa_group>
            <wd:Reference_ID_Value>001</wd:Reference_ID_Value>
        </wd:Empresa_group>
        <wd:location wd:Descriptor="CIUDAD BBVA [BBVA]">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">33f2c90f9fd40151e4a2ebc722146777</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Location_ID">00018800_ESP01</wd:ID>
        </wd:location>
        <wd:location_group>
            <wd:country wd:Descriptor="España">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">bd34c524a6a04ae6915f5d96fa086199</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code">ES</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-3_Code">ESP</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Numeric-3_Code">724</wd:ID>
            </wd:country>
        </wd:location_group>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

And i need this output

Id_de_Empleado|Skill_Reference_ID|Reference_ID_Value|Country

`"00003500294","046","001","ES"`

`"00003500294","125","001","ES"`

But with the xslt that i made:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/INT0254_JDDATIO_039_Workday_to_Datio_Worker-Work_Experience_Outbound_RD" version="2.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt" xmlns:etv="urn:com.workday/etv">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Linefeed" select="'&#xd;&#xa;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="EMPTY" select="''"/>
    <xsl:variable name="HASHTAG" select="substring-after(wd:Experiencia_profesional_group/wd:Skill_Reference_ID, '#')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="CONCAT" select="concat(wd:Experiencia_profesional_group/wd:Skill_Reference_ID,$EMPTY)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <File xtt:separator="&#xd;&#xa;">
            <Header xtt:separator="," xtt:truncate="true" xtt:quotes="always">
                <Title1>g_worker_id</Title1>
                <Title2>g_employee_work_experience_id</Title2>
                <Title3>g_internal_company_id</Title3>
                <Title4>g_country_id</Title4>
            </Header>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Report_Data"/>
        </File>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length(wd:ID_de_empleado) &lt;=11">
                <Record xtt:separator="&#xd;&#xa;" xtt:quotes="always" xtt:truncate="true">
                    <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry">
                        <xsl:if test="not(wd:Experiencia_profesional_group/wd:Skill_Reference_ID = '')">
                            <Worker_Experience xtt:separator="," xtt:quotes="always" xtt:truncate="true">
                                <Employee_ID xtt:required="true" xtt:maxLength="11">
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="wd:ID_de_empleado"/>
                                </Employee_ID>
                                <xsl:for-each select="wd:Experiencia_profesional_group">
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="string-length($HASHTAG) &gt; 3 and string-length (wd:Skill_Reference_ID) &lt; 1">
                                            <Work_experience_ID xtt:required="true" xtt:maxLength="3">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="$EMPTY"/>
                                            </Work_experience_ID>
                                            <errormessage xtt:omit="true" xtt:severity="error" xtt:target="ID Experiencia" xtt:message="El registro supera los 3 caracteres - ID Experiencia">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="$EMPTY"/>
                                            </errormessage>
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <Work_experience_ID>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="wd:Skill_Reference_ID"/>
                                            </Work_experience_ID>
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="string-length(wd:Empresa_group/wd:Reference_ID_Value) &gt; 3">
                                        <Company xtt:required="true" xtt:maxLength="3">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$EMPTY"/>
                                        </Company>
                                        <errormessage xtt:omit="true" xtt:severity="error" xtt:target="Compañia" xtt:message="El registro supera los 3 caracteres - ID Compañia">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$EMPTY"/>
                                        </errormessage>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <Company>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="wd:Empresa_group/wd:Reference_ID_Value"/>
                                        </Company>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                                <Country xtt:required="true" xtt:maxLength="2">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(wd:location_group/wd:country/wd:ID [@wd:type='ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code'], $Linefeed)"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$EMPTY"/>
                                </Country>
                            </Worker_Experience>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Record>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**I'm getting this one:**

Id_de_Empleado|Skill_Reference_ID|Reference_ID_Value|Country

> 00003500294,"046","125","001","ES"

How can I make the iteration to get the output I need?

Comment: The XML you posted is not valid.

Comment: Done, i had one mistake with the copy/paste

Comment: It's still not a well-formed XML document. In addition,  please explain the logic you want to apply in words, rather than just dumping some random values as the expected output and expect as to figure it out..

Comment: Your XML is still not valid. Also you state that you want an output like "00003500294","046","001","ES" and you post an XSLT that creates a big XML structure?

Comment: Now, that your [mcve] is complete: there is a vast difference between the actual output and the output you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comma separated output can be achieved with a few lines of XSLT 3:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.workday.report/INT0254_JDDATIO_039_Workday_to_Datio_Worker-Work_Experience_Outbound_RD"
  xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/INT0254_JDDATIO_039_Workday_to_Datio_Worker-Work_Experience_Outbound_RD"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Report_Data/Report_Entry/Experiencia_profesional_group/Skill_Reference_ID"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Skill_Reference_ID">
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Report_Entry!(ID_de_empleado, current(), Empresa_group/Reference_ID_Value, location_group/country/wd:ID[@wd:type= 'ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code'])" separator=","/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```